# How do I sum columns which contain a certain string in the column heading?

Tags: r

I have a dataframe containing a bunch of columns with the string "hsehold" in the headers, and a bunch of columns containing the string "away" in the headers. (eg. hsehold1, hsehold2, hsehold3, away1, away2, away3)

I want to add a column to the dataframe containing the sum of the values in all columns containing "hsehold" in the header.

This is the code I've tried:

`df$newCol.hsehold <- rowSums(df, na.rm = TRUE, select(matches("hsehold")))`
and
`df$newCol.hsehold <- rowSums(df, na.rm = TRUE, select(contains("hsehold")))`

I get the error message:
contains()` must be used within a *selecting* function.

Comment: `df$newCol.hsehold <- rowSums(select(df, matches("hsehold")), na.rm = TRUE)`

Answer (score 0):

Try `rowSums(df[,grepl("hsehold",colnames(df)])`.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure how to upvote a comment on my question.

Ronak Shah commented (instead of adding an answer) to correct my code.

It was successful, thank you!

Here's what they suggested:

```
df$newCol.hsehold <- rowSums(select(df, matches("hsehold")), na.rm = TRUE)
```

Comment: You haven't overlooked the upvoting button, don't worry. Voting up and down are privileges only earned with certain scores ("reputation") on stackoverflow (see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges) for an overview of privileges).

Comment: Thanks! Is there any other way for me to give the right person (Ronak Shah) the credit they are due?

Comment: Not that I know of. Maybe you'll remember when you got the necessary score. If they were super eager on earning credit, they could have presented their solution as an answer instead of a comment.